# Vector Plane Equation Proof

Tags: vectors

> Let A,B and C be points in three-dimensional space with position
> vectors $ \vec a,\vec b,\vec c $ respectively. Given that these points
> are not collinear show that the plane which contains A,B and C can be
> described by the vector equation $$ \vec r=\lambda \vec a + \mu \vec b
> + v\vec c, $$ where $\lambda + \mu + v = 1.$

I started with the vector plane equation that I know which is $ \vec r \cdot \vec n=\vec f \cdot \vec n$ where $\vec n$ is the normal vector to the plane and $\vec f$ is the position vector of an arbitrary point on the plane (in this case $\vec a, \vec b$ or $\vec c$).

I started by finding $\vec n$ by computing $ (\vec b - \vec a) \times (\vec c- \vec a)$ which can be expanded to give $$ \vec n= \vec b \times \vec c + \vec a \times \vec b + \vec c \times \vec a.$$ For my case I took $\vec f = \vec a$ then by expanding dot products I got to the following $$ \vec r \cdot (\vec b \times \vec c + \vec a \times \vec b + \vec c \times \vec a)= \vec a \cdot (\vec b \times \vec c).$$

This is where I am stuck, can we somehow infer from this equation that $\vec r$ must be composed of $\vec a, \vec b,\vec c$ ?

Comment: I am not used to this notation, but notice that the direction of the plane is generated by the vectors $\{ ab, ac \}$, which are linearly independent by the non collinearity condition. Therefore, every point in the plane can be written as $P = A + \lambda ab + \mu ac = (1-\lambda - \mu) A + \lambda B + \mu C$

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm not sure I have been introduced to this idea. What does {$ab,ac$} mean?

Comment: I was in mobile, wanted to save notation. $ab = \vec{b}-\vec{a}$

Comment: Ah ok. Yes that makes sense now thank you for your help.

Comment: It may help to first note that the line through $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ is the set $$\{\vec a + t(\vec b - \vec a)\mid t \in \Bbb R\}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{AC}$ are not collinear, but are coplanar to the required plane, which contains the point $A.$

Therefore, the plane has parametric vector equation \begin{align}\vec r&= \vec a + \mu \vec{AB} + v\vec {AC} \\&= (1-\mu-v)\vec a + \mu \vec b + v\vec c \\&= \lambda\vec a + \mu \vec b + v\vec c,\end{align} where $\lambda=1-\mu-v,$ i.e., $$\lambda+\mu+v=1.$$